# How to make loggings appear on Tkinter GUI or on any text widget while code execution?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, logging, listbox

I have a Tkinter simple project to get some data from a webbrowser using Selenium.
I was using the logging module to mark the code execution and was trying to make these logs appear on any text widget whether Label, Entry, or Listbox.
My problem is when the code runs logs appear normally on the console screen, but inserting the same comments into the Entry box or List box appear all combined after the function is executed. Is there a way to show logs directly on Tkinter GUI? or a way I can make inserting the same comments work as logging but on GUI?
or generally, is there a way I can show console execution on Tkinter GUI?

```
def open_page():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    logging.info('Browser launched')
    results.insert(1, 'Browser launched') # trying to insert same comment into a Listbox
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get('#link')
    logging.info('Page requested')
    results.insert(2, 'Page requested')
    time.sleep(5)

results = Listbox(main, justify='left')
results.config(font=30, bg=bg_color)
results.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.5)
```

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Use `main.after(5000, <function to call after 5 sec>)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I had no trouble using the time.sleep function, my main issue was getting the logging data to be viewed on a Tkinter widget in real-time. any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is caused by `time.sleep(...)`. That is why I suggested you use `.after` to schedule a function call after 5 seconds.